# how to multiply two unequal matrices in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

```
c1=[1 2 3 4 5 6];
c2=[4 5 6 7 8 9 10];    
c3=[3 5 7 11 12 13];

o1=intersect(c1,union(c2,c3)); 
o2=intersect(c2,union(c1,c3));  
o3=intersect(c3,union(c1,c2));  

p=(c1.*c2).*c3;  

ND21=1;  
ND22=2;  
ND23=3;  

CIa1=1/(ND21);  
CIa2=1/(ND22);  
CIa3=1/(ND23);  

CIp1=(c1-o1)/p; 
CIp2=(c2-o2)/p;  
CIp3=(c3-o3)/p;  

Eavg1=(Ecur1+Ecur2+Ecur3)/ND21;  
Eavg2=(Ecur1+Ecur2+Ecur3)/ND22;  
Eavg3=(Ecur1+Ecur2+Ecur3)/ND23;
```

---

i want multiply `c1` and `c2` which is an unequal matrix. I'm getting the following error:

```
??? Error using ==> times
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in ==> batwsn at 13

p=(c1.*c2).*c3;
```

Comment: You can't. Matrix multiplication is only defined for matrices if the width of the first one is the same as the height of the second one.

Comment: K how to pad the zero's...

Comment: if i'm padding zero's to c1 and c3 than output of o1,o2,o3 getting different value. And for CIp1,CIp2 and CIp3 will get differ so what i have to do plz help me...

Comment: Can you give an example to the results that you expect to get?

Comment: like o1 =[3 4 5 6],o2 =[4 5 6 7],o3 =[3 5 7]; so know i want to get "p" result

Answer (score 0):

The rule for matrix multiplication is that two matrices can be multiplied only when the number of columns in the first equals the number of rows in the second.  This is a mathematical principle so basically you should not expect MatLab to do it.

The closest you can come is to pad one of the matrices with zeros to get the dimensions to match the rules - **but** you may not get the results you are expecting.

Comment: ya k, by padding the zero i can get the value of 'p' but for CIp1,CIp2 and CIp3 i'm not getting sir...